# yarn install "error Received malformed response from registry"

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I've been trying to run `docker-compose up` inside a project. The issue is everytime I run this command, it crashes with the following message:

```
error Received malformed response from registry for "strong-globalize". The registry may be down.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Received malformed response from registry for "qs". The registry may be down.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50508:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:328:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:307:12)
    at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50550:19)
Error: Received malformed response from registry for "strong-globalize". The registry may be down.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50508:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:328:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:307:12)
    at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50550:19)
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --network-timeout 300000000' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Everytime the message is different saying a different registry gave a malformed response. I'm running this on docker quickstart terminal inside Windows 10 Education. Here is the proof that everytime the package install that returns a malformed response is a different one:

```
error Couldn't find package "@types/node@*" required by "@types/connect@*" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/node@*" required by "@types/body-parser@*" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/node@*" required by "@types/express-serve-static-core@^4.17.18" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/node@*" required by "@types/serve-static@*" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --network-timeout 300000000' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build


Error: Received malformed response from registry for "@types%2fnode". The registry may be down.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50508:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:328:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:307:12)
    at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50550:19)
Error: Received malformed response from registry for "@types%2fnode". The registry may be down.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50508:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:328:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:307:12)
    at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50550:19)


    error Received malformed response from registry for "loopback-datasource-juggler". The registry may be down.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Received malformed response from registry for "loopback-datasource-juggler". The registry may be down.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50508:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:328:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:307:12)
    at Function.findVersionInRegistryResponse (/opt/yarn-v1.22.5/lib/cli.js:50550:19)
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --network-timeout 300000000' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried the following fixes and none worked:

1. Adding `--network-timeout 30000000` to the yarn install command inside the dockerfile.
2. Adding the `yarn cache clean` command before yarn install inside the dockerfile.
3. Updating yarn and npm to latest versions.

Please help ):

Comment: "The registry might be down" is a hint here. Are you sure it's alive? That it's not being blocked by any firewalls or firewall rules?

Comment: 1. Done, took out screenshots.

Comment: 2. The registry is not down, I can run the yarn install command with no issue outside the docker compose command. (It appears the issue comes from trying to run yarn install inside the docker container)

Comment: It could be related to networking inside your container. Can you test something simple, like `curl https://example.com` to see if you can actually reach the outside world?

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: curl: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c curl https://example.com' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Well, whatever you can get working. You need to verify that it works. `curl` is common. NPM also has other tools for fetching things. Like can you `yarn install` *anything*? Pick a random package without an `@` namespace prefix.

Comment: Yes, I can yarn install something but the issue is with the batch command when in tries to install everything inside the package.json file. It always crashes in some random package (like shown in the errors).

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same problem.